# How to get a relative path to a target with CMake?

Tags: bash, cmake

I have a project that uses CMake to generate build scripts, and each platform puts the executable that are generated in a different place. We have a non-programmer on our team who does not have build tools and I want to be able to bundle up all the files, scripts and executables necessary to run the project so that he can run the project.

To do that, I've added a custom target that takes all the necessary files and zips them up. It also generates a very simple script (which is included in the zip file) that he can just click on that should run a script then launch the executable, like so:

```
add_custom_target(runcommand
  COMMAND echo '\#!/bin/bash -eu' > run.command &&
          echo 'cd `dirname $$0`' >> run.command &&
          echo './scripts/prerun_script.sh && ${MY_EXECUTABLE}' >> run.command &&
          chmod +x run.command)
```

The problem with this is that MY_EXECUTABLE is a hardcoded path to the executable on my system. I would like it to be a relative path so that I can just take this resultant zip file, unzip it anywhere and run it from there. What I would like is to get the path to MY_EXECUTABLE relative to the root directory of my project so that this script can be run from anywhere.

Comment: Your question is about relative paths in CMake. But the solution for the problem you're describing is not really the CMake way of doing things. CMake together with CPack supports installing targets. These install targets can then be packaged either as a zip, tgz, debian package. All this is done in a platform independent way. Your solution is platform specific since it uses a bash script. http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack

Comment: To a minimum you should consider using the `install()` command and then zip the results rather than a custom target.

Answer (score 19):

You can use:

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH variable directory file)
```

Concretely, assume that `MY_ROOT` contains the root directory (there might be a suitable predefined CMake variable for this), this will set `rel` to the relative path of `MY_EXECUTABLE`:

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH rel ${MY_ROOT} ${MY_EXECUTABLE})
```

Answer (score 3):

In case where you want to get path relative to project root, you may use [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) CMake variable:

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH rel ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${MY_EXECUTABLE})
```

Remember, that `MY_EXECUTABLE` must contain full path to file.

Answer (score 1):

get the relative path to the current source directory

```
file(RELATIVE_PATH relative ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Test:

```
message(STATUS "source base: \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\"")
message(STATUS "current: \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\"")
message(STATUS "relative: \"${relative}\"")
```

Result:

```
--source base: "C:/Project/Software/Test/source"
--current: "C:/Project/Software/Test/source/unittest/libs/fsm
--relative: "unittest/libs/fsm"
```

Comment: This works! But If you are like me and trying to package this into a .deb, you are better off putting the file into a shared spot like `/usr/share/PROJECT/myfile.txt`.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this would work:

```
THISDIR=`pwd`
MY_EXECUTABLE=$THISDIR/test/someexec
REL_EXECUTABLE=${MY_EXECUTABLE##$THISDIR/}
echo $REL_EXECUTABLE
```

Basically, this chops off the base path from `$MY_EXECUTABLE`. In this example, I just set up `MY_EXECUTABLE` as a test to give it a full path. The one-line equivalent for what you want is:

```
${MY_EXECUTABLE##`pwd`/}
```

I guess this assumes `pwd` is the root of your project. Otherwise, see the [Cmake variable](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) doc.

(As an aside, this makes me nostalgic for the `ksh` days.)

Comment: I'm going to give this a try in just a minute. Is that ## special syntax to chop part of the string off? Is that part of CMake or Bash?

Comment: It's bash. It means chop off the front part of the var that matches the string. `%%` is chop off the end. You can also use `%` or `#`, which I think is the smallest match, where if you double up, it removes the largest match.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about CMake

Comment: @Joakim the question was also tagged bash, and the question example is dynamically creating a bash script, so, it's about both CMake and bash.