# How do I convert CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_PATH to a relative path under CMAKE_SOURCE_PATH in CMake?

Tags: cmake, relative-path

I have a [custom target which creates a pair of files](https://github.com/m2osw/advgetopt/blob/main/cmake/AtomicNamesConfig.cmake). The current version has a *global* name:

```
function(AtomicNames ATOMIC_NAMES)
    cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 1 "" "" "" "")

    project(${ATOMIC_NAMES}_AtomicNames)

    ...
```

This version allows me to create one set of *AtomicNames* per project assuming I want to reuse the same filename (I would like to use `names.an` everywhere for consistency).

So what I'm looking for is a way to change the `project()` name using the current local path. Say I have two directories: `src` and `tools`, I would like to have:

```
project(src_names_AtomicNames)

-- and --

project(tools_names_AtomicNames)
```

So I'd like to extract the relative path as defined between the top CMake source directory (`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`) and the current source directory (`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`). Is there a cmake function to do this?

Details:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2
```

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433033/how-to-get-a-relative-path-to-a-target-with-cmake) about obtaining a relative path?

Comment: Oh now I see the answer was there. I did see that question! We can mark my question as a dup.